# How can I access TSensorManager.Activate?

Tags: delphi, winapi, sensors

I'm trying to access a Light Sensor on my notebook (MacBook Pro with Windows 10) using Delphi 10.3 Community Edition.

```
uses
  System.Sensors;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LManager : TSensorManager;
begin
  LManager := TSensorManager.Current;
  LManager.Activate;
end;
```

But while calling `LManager.Activate` I get an `EOleSysError` exception saying "Access denied".

I tried to execute the program as Administrator.

Inside the Device Manager of Windows, there is this light sensor listed and it should work as well.

I'm running Windows 10 64-bit, but the target device inside Delphi is 32-bit.

Any ideas how I can access the light sensor?

**Update:**

This seems not to be a hardware or a Windows problem. The app "[Light Sensor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/light-sensor/9nblggh10zxn/0010?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)" can read the state of the sensor and I re-installed Windows 10.

Comment: Per the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Sensors.TSensorManager.Activate): "*Note: **Check the return value of [CanActivate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Sensors.TSensorManager.CanActivate) before you call Activate** to check whether the system supports [sensor managers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Sensors.TSensorManager).*"

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: Yes, `CanActivate` retunrs `True` [ISensorManager::RequestPermissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sensorsapi/nf-sensorsapi-isensormanager-requestpermissions) fails. How can I allow the light sensor in Windows 10? Maybe i disallowed the usage of it before...

Comment: I can't really answer that. Check the OS configuration, check the sensor driver/firmware. This is not a coding issue anymore

Comment: @NilsWeg Please refer to "[Managing User Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sensorsapi/managing-user-permissions)"(You may want to request permission when you want to use sensors for which the current SensorState is SENSOR_STATE_ACCESS_DENIED.). Hope it helps.